# confusion between two rewrite urls rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

these two rules are confused :

```
RewriteRule ^health-institute-([a-zA-Z\-]+)-([a-zA-Z\-]+)$ search.php?city=$1&speciality=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^health-institute-app-([a-zA-Z\-]+)$ search.php?city=$1 [L]
```

when I want to reach `health-institute-app-mycity` (2nd rule)  the server consider `app` as a value and try to reach `search.php?city=app&speciality=mycity` (1st rule)

how can I say that these are two separate rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because the regex `^health-institute-([a-zA-Z\-]+)-([a-zA-Z\-]+)$` in the first rule also matches `health-institute-app-mycity`.

You need to reverse these two directives so the more specific rule is first.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^health-institute-app-([a-zA-Z-]+)$ search.php?city=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^health-institute-([a-zA-Z-]+)-([a-zA-Z-]+)$ search.php?city=$1&speciality=$2 [L]
```

(No need to backslash-escape the hyphen when at the start or end of the character class.)

HOWEVER, the regex in the (now) second rule is potentially ambiguous since the hyphen (`-`) is used to delimit the two values (`city` and `speciality`), but the hyphen is also included in both the character classes, so it can presumably be part of the values themselves. However, both `city` *and* `speciality` cannot both contain hyphens, despite the regex seemingly allowing this.

For example, how should a request for `health-institute-foo-bar-baz-qux` be resolved? Since the quantifier `+` is *greedy*, this will currently result in `search.php?city=foo-bar-baz&speciality=qux`. If there is ever a hyphen in the `speciality` (as suggested this could be the case by the regex) it will never be matched.

Comment: @narseoh Actually, since these values are delimited by a hyphen, by including the hyphen in the character classes (ie. the values themselves can contain a hyphen) you are introducing an ambiguity. eg. What should `health-institute-foo-bar-baz-qux` resolve to? Can the `city` contain hyphens?

Comment: Yes indeed, some cities have a hyphen in the city name and other cities have two words, the space is replaced by a hyphen in the url

Comment: @narseoh OK, so the `speciality` never contains a hyphen? (Otherwise, it will become part of the `city`.) In which case the hyphen should be removed from the `speciality` character class, to remove this ambiguity/confusion, since it is superfluous.

Comment: thanks @MrWhite , actually even speciality could have an hyphen which makes things a little more complicated for me.
I thought about it and replaced (-) with (/) to separate the data, that said I had other issues (I'll create another thread about it)